# Node.js app deployed by Heroku receiving empty array from a full db in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

My app should fetch movie data from a mongodb database, but is returning an empty array. It is deployed through heroku. I feel like I've tried everything and can't figure out the problem.

Here is the cluster on MongoAtlas:
[screenshot of MongoAtlas structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSp7B.png)

Here is the server side code:

```
const express = require ('express'),
  fs = require('fs'), // import built in node modules fs and path 
  path = require('path'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  uuid = require('uuid'),
  morgan = require('morgan'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  dotenv = require('dotenv').config(),
  Models = require('./models.js');

const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

const Movies = Models.Movie;
const Users = Models.User;

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());


//allow mongoose to connect to jMDB
//CONNECTION_URI is defined in .env file (and as a config variable in Heroku)
mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error('MongoDb connection failed: ' + err));
  mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('MongoDb connection error: ' + err);
  });


//needs to be before authorization & any middleware (morgan)
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

//import auth.js
let auth = require('./auth')(app);

const passport = require('passport');
require('./passport');

// create a write stream (in append mode) (‘log.txt’ file is created in root directory)
const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'log.txt'), {flags: 'a'})

// setup the logger
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}));
app.use('/documentation.html', express.static('public/documentation.html'));

//check URI
console.log("Connection URI:", process.env.CONNECTION_URI);


//GET Movies
app.get('/movies', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    Movies.find()
    .then((movies) => {
        console.log('Movies fetched:', movies);
        res.status(200).json(movies);
        })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });
});

//error handling with express
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
  });

  
// listen for requests
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0',() => {
 console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
});
```

Including my models.js code in case someone can spot an issue there:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

let movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {type: String, required: true},
    Director: [{ Name: String, Description: String, required:false}],
    ImagePath: {type: String},
    Description: {type: String, required: true},
    Tags: [{ Name: String, Description: String}],
    Featured: {type: Boolean}
}, {collection: 'movies'})

let Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);

module.exports.Movie = Movie;
```

I've also tried defining the movieSchema without the `, {collection: 'movies}` and it doesn't change anything.

How I'm testing:

1. on Postman with valid authorization/authentication = Empty Array
2. checking my heroku logs  =

```
2023-06-06T13:34:54.294260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/movies" host=jmdb.herokuapp.com request_id=1687210f-2835-4874-ba52-02c3fa397adb fwd="IpAddress" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1ms status=204 bytes=302 protocol=https
2023-06-06T13:34:54.350330+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/movies" host=jmdb.herokuapp.com request_id=15ab91ad-9e82-4718-9a55-853c819100d4 fwd="IpAddress" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=40ms status=200 bytes=239 protocol=https
2023-06-06T13:34:54.347403+00:00 app[web.1]: Movies fetched: []
```

3. via localhost:1234 because my client side code isn't fully merged with my backend code (for some reason. ...following the bootcamp curriculum :()
   -I've added a bunch of console.logs and the fetch is working, but data for movies coming back with empty arrays.
   --LMK if the client frontend would be helpful, but I'm pretty sure the issue is on the backend

thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Are you actually specifying that app should query the `jMDB` database (from a namespace perspective as opposed to the Atlas cluster perspective)? Apart from credentials, what is your connection string? Perhaps you are querying the collection in the wrong namespace (eg the `test` database) hence the empty results

Comment: That's a great question.  The URI MongoAtlas provided includes the cluster's name `jmdb-db`. 
I just tried editing the CONNECTION_URI config variable in heroku settings and in my .env file from `"mongodb+srv://jaceyhallock:<myPassword>@jmdb-db.1n9xhuf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` (with cluster name)
to `"mongodb+srv://jaceyhallock:<myPassword>@jmdb.1n9xhuf.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` and it's still connecting in the same way and returning an empty array.

I also tried it with `jMDB` and `jmdb-db/jMDB` and the data response is empty arrays.

Comment: I think there was a copy paste error with your two connection strings in the previous comment (they seem the same to me). Basically [this example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#records-database) is what I'm referring to. Either the client or the connection string needs to specify which logical database (namespace) to process queries against. If you're successfully getting an empty response my guess is that the app is connecting to the cluster but querying the wrong (nonexistent) collection/namespace (which indeed returns empty instead of erroring)